# R: Adjusted proportions of weighted sample data from NHANES

Tags: r, statistics, stata, survey

I am conducting research using NHANES data from CDC.

I applied weights to my sample data by using 'survey' package and am using 'survey design' object to conduct further analyses.

What I am struggling now (hard to find the same question), is **getting a certain proportions with adjustment for age, gender, race with this weighted sample.**

**I have 5 independent group of increasing tendency (1,2,3,4,5)
and want to get the proportion of obesity of each group after adjusting for age, sex & race.**

I found the package called ‘DirectStandardisation’ (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DirectStandardisation/DirectStandardisation.pdf),
which seem to support 'adjprop' function. However, it doesn't seem to take 'survey design' as an argument, which means it only takes usual data frame as an argument.

I also hardly found the concept of '**adjusted proportion**' which I am required to get.

1. Is it so-called standardised proportion? If so, should I use either direct standardization or indirect standardization methods?
2. In case of direct standardization, do I have to make new weights other than sampling weights(adjusting sampling bias, non-response)?
3. If I should use direct standardization method, do I follow census proportion for age? and which proportion should I follow for gender or race?
   (0.5/0.5 for gender?)
4. it seems that what I have to do is corresponding to the 'adjprop' function in Stata as far as I was informed - and in Stata, it seems that I am able to incorporate weighted design to use that function.
   Any equivalent in R? Am I missing some important basics?

I am new to this type of research and learning from the scratch one by one.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/blob/archive/National%20Health%20and%20Nutrition%20Examination%20Survey/2009-2010%20interview%20plus%20laboratory%20-%20download%20and%20analyze.R#L418  ?